# get data from multiple views in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i need to get user data from multiple views and save them. user may get back to previous view and edit data.(swift))

consider the below link for reference -
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7gEscyiNhh0MUpfU0tOWXliazQ&usp=sharing

It contains views for adding property

1. in first view(list my property ) they will choose the type after tapping it should move to next view
   2.that is property details after filling and tapping next it should navigate to contact details 
   3.after filling and submitting it should display thanks view

problem is how should i get data from multiple views other than using prepare segue method  is there any alternative ?
or how should i achieve this ?

Comment: create an object with the properties you want and allocate it the first view and pass it to subsequent views. Objects in swift are passed by reference, so, whenever any property is changed, this change may be accessed by any view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new class object to store the information which is added to on each page and then passed using prepareForSegue, using the below code you would just pass the 'details' object and use dot syntax to add to it in each screen.

```
class selectedDetails {

enum propertyType {

 case None
 case Sale
 case Rent
 case PGHostels
}

enum listedBy {

 case None
 case Landlord
 case Agent
}

var listType = propertyType.None

var address = String()

var by = listedBy.None
}

var details = selectedDetails()

details.listType = .Rent
details.address = "Address details"
details.by = .Landlord
```